# Using user_passes_test Restrict Access to View by Group or Logged in User

Tags: python, django

Users have individual profiles where I am trying to restrict their access to their individual profile while allowing users in an admin Group to access all profiles.

Ideally I was hoping to accomplish this by way of the decorator user_passes_test with one function. If need be I could use two different functions with a decorator for each. Though combining all into one may be cleaner.

```py
# Views.py

def profile_access(CustomUser, request):
    officer = CustomUser.groups.filter(name='Officer')
    logged_in_user = request.self.CustomUser
    if officer or logged_in_user:
        return True
    else:
        return redirect('homepage')


@user_passes_test(profile_access)
def profile(request, pk):
    # Profile content here
```

I am not sure how to identify the logged in user to restrict them to their Profile only while also allowing users in the Officer group to see all Profiles.

Update:

```py
# accounts models.py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    authorization_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-home', args=[str(self.pk)])


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    officer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    regdate = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    active_player = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    clan_battle_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    captain = models.ManyToManyField(ShipCaptain)
    ships = models.ManyToManyField(NavalShip)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in that code, but in any case this is not something you could do in a user_passes_test function; the request is not passed, so there is no way of telling if the user is accessing their own profile.

Do this inside the view.

Comment: Daniel: What do you recommend writing in the view?

Comment: Well I can't really tell from the code you've posted. What identifies a profile as belonging to a user? Show the models.

Comment: Posted an update with the additional information whenever you have a chance. Thank you.